# OpenGL. coordinates after translation

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, 3d

I'm trying to learn OpenGL. At first, I have the following code:

```
gluLookAt(0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Then, at each iteration of the main loop I apply the translation:

```
glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, t)
```

What is an easiest way to get new center point after each iteration?

Comment: Get the modelview matrix from OpenGL using `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)` and apply it to the point.

Comment: This is normally easier when you work with more moden opengl where you define your own matrices with for example the `pyrr` library. Fixed pipeline makes things like this a bit awkward.